# Simple Entity Framework query against SQL Server Compact DB throws an exception

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-ce

Why does this code throw an error?

Simple console app in C#, connection string for `DbContext` is

```
|DataDirectory|database.sdf
```

Database is in `bin\Debug` folder as `database.sdf` with 9 records. SQL Server Compact 4.0

```
var localCredential = Db.Credentials
                        .OrderByDescending(p => p.DateCreated)
                        .FirstOrDefault();
```

Error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Can you share the line or full exception? It gives on Db call or after processing localCredential variable?

Comment: What is Db - is it properly initialized?

Comment: Totally weird, suddenly it started to work after I posted the question...wtf